# Central limit theorem for asymptotic uncorrelated stationary sequence

Tags: time-series, normal-distribution, independence, markov-process, central-limit-theorem

I am following Patrick Billingsley,  Probability and measure (1995). He says that there exists a central limit theorem if the sequence is stationary $\alpha$-mixing with $\alpha_n = O(n^{-5})$. He goes on to saying that $\alpha_n = O(n^{-5})$ is stronger than necessary.

$\rho$-mixing (asymptotic uncorrelated) is stronger than $\alpha$-mixing. I am interested in $\rho$-mixing sequence of stationary random variables. I need to see that the mean of such a sequence is asymptotic normal. Can you provide a reference that my conditions are strong enough, or propose light additional conditions which suffices?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The excellent review by Richard Bradley [Basic Properties of Strong Mixing
Conditions. A Survey and Some Open
Questions](https://arxiv.org/pdf/math/0511078.pdf) seems to contain a lot of the references you are looking for. Section 6.4 in the article seems particularly relevant.

Also, $\rho$-mixing is weaker than $\phi$-mixing and $\psi$-mixing, results for them will be pertinent to you as well.